# Gnome3, Systemd and umask

Tags: systemd, gnome3

I try to configure how Nautilus, GEdit and other Gnome applications set new file and directory permissions (002 instead of the default 022).

After reading posts and trying things, I found a "working" solution. All the users use these settings :

```
mkdir /etc/systemd/user/dbus.service.d/
mkdir /etc/systemd/user/gnome-terminal-server.service.d/
echo -e "[Service]\nUMask=002\n" > /etc/systemd/user/dbus.service.d/override.conf
echo -e "[Service]\nUMask=002\n" > /etc/systemd/user/gnome-terminal-server.service.d/override.conf
```

After reading a few more posts I removed these files and directories and tried :

```
mkdir /etc/systemd/system/user@.service.d/
echo -e "[Service]\nUMask=002\n" > /etc/systemd/system/user@.service.d/override.conf
```

I did this because both dbus.service and gnome-terminal-server.service are under user@1000.service (systemd-cgls):

```
Control group /:
-.slice
├─user.slice
│ ├─user-1000.slice
│ │ └─user@1000.service
│ │   ├─gnome-terminal-server.service
│ │   │ ├─1763 /usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server
│ │   │ ├─1771 bash
│ │   ├─dbus.service
│ │   │ └─1973 /usr/bin/nautilus --gapplication-service
```

Unfortunately, executing umask in my terminal prints 0022 and not 0002 but GEdit and Nautilus use 002 (I created a new text file and a new directory).

What am I missing ?

Comment: Does your shell set the umask somewhere else (such as `~/.profile` or `/etc/profile`)?

Comment: No, I checked ~/.bashrc too. I never modify these files. If the first solution works for my terminals, we can probably assume bash doesn't override the umask.

Answer (score 1):

At least on fedora, bash overwrites the umask in `/etc/bashrc`

Comment: Really? Are you sure?

Comment: @G-Man yes, it does, for non-login shells: for uids starting at 200, if the user matches the group name, it’s set to 002, otherwise 022.

Comment: @StephenKitt: What we have here is a failure to communicate.  I guess you're saying that bash ***overrides*** the umask in ```/etc/bashrc```.  I read the above answer as saying that bash ***overwrites** the **file*** ```/etc/bashrc```, which I (still) doubt.

Comment: @G-Man ah, right, yes, bash doesn’t overwrite `/etc/bashrc`, but if the author had meant that, why mention “the umask in”?

Comment: @StephenKitt If I modified a file, unconditionally setting a new value for one parameter (ignoring its existing value) and leaving the rest of the file unchanged, I might use similar language.

Comment: @G-Man I see what you mean — “bash rewrites `/etc/bashrc`, fixing up the umask set there”. That didn’t occur to me at all!

Answer (score 0):

I have the workaround at least on Fedora 31:

```
sudo vi /etc/profile.d/umask.sh
umask <your_umask>

sudo vi /etc/login.defs
UMASK <your_umask>

sudo vi /usr/local/bin/systemd-user
/usr/lib/systemd/systemd --user

sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/systemd-user

sudo vi /usr/lib/systemd/system/user@.service
ExecStart=-/usr/local/bin/systemd-user
```

It enables umask in all gnome apps launched by 'systemd --user' and enables umask in gnome-terminal too.

Comment: Can you explain what that does?